# Basic kerning with XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, lyx, fontspec, kerning

Trying to use custom fonts with LyX, so I started using XeTeX.
Unfortunately, It seems kerning only works with certain OpenType fonts (Linux Libertine) but not for others (Doulos SIL or Charis SIL).

Are there additional settings I have to set up in order for this to work?

**Edit:** Images from the pdf output (with Linux Libertine and Doulos SIL respectively):
[image: Kerning with Linux Libertine]
[image: No kerning with Doulos SIL]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Kerning is activated by default. If you don't get kerning you either deactivated it somehow (see documentation of fontspec for informations) or your font doesn't have the kerning informations (or use rather small values).

Comment: Ulrike - I don't think I deactivated it, since I'm simply choosing the font. The moment I switch back, it works OK again.

Comment: From this page here: [Unicode IPA fonts](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_IPA.html) it appears that the SIL Doulos and Charis fonts have no kerning pairs. (Which isn't too surprising since they were designed primarily as phonetic fonts for which kerning doesn't make a lot of sense.)

Comment: Alan - great answer. Want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This is a combination of my and Ulrike's comments.)

Kerning is activated by default. If you don't get kerning you either deactivated it somehow (see documentation of `fontspec` for information) or your font doesn't have the kerning information (or uses rather small values).

From this page here: [Unicode IPA fonts](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_IPA.html) it appears that the SIL Doulos and Charis fonts have no kerning pairs. This fact isn't too surprising since they were designed primarily as phonetic fonts for which kerning doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Why doesn't kerning make sense for phonetic phonts?

Comment: Welp. That was a weird typo. I'm leaving it up there for posterity.

Comment: :-) Well for their use in linguistics they are generally used in relatively small stretches of text, (usually individual words) rather than running text meant to be read like a paragraph. And individuation of the particular symbols is more important than nice looking spacing, IMO.  The SIL people have released a lot of fonts, and they know quite a bit about what they are doing, so I suspect this decision was either deliberate or at least made a very low priority for these fonts.